# How do you express the idea that someone is getting worse and worse grades in their tests/exams?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request, sentence-request

Let's say William is performing worse and worse in his tests/exams recently, how do you describe this situation? Is it natural to use the word 'regress'?

> William is regressing in his studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"regressing" isn't really an idiomatic and natural word that people use.

You could try:

> failing
>
> dropping
>
> Or the simple **his grades are decreasing**

Comment: I would never use "decreasing" on its own. It would have to be that his grades are decreasing, not that he is decreasing. But I wouldn't even use it then.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you put in your description, I would use either **getting worse** or **not improving**. If you're looking for a single word, it would probably be **failing**:

> William, your grades are getting worse....
>
> William, your grades are not improving...
>
> William, you are failing.

These are only a few suggestions. There are many ways to say this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though his work is **deteriorating**. See https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deteriorate